# How to choose where to start a mysql_fetch_row?

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to query a database and split the result between near evenly between two article containers.  The function is called in both containers and runs one block (if or else) and outputs the results.

The function uses a static counter and increments at the end of it's call to increment so the next call activates the second part.

Since I wanted two containers split near equally, I use mysql_num_rows($result) to find total number of rows then divide it by two and round it into the variable $halfWay.  An for loop is run in an if block until the increment is less than halfway. It increments $counter and ends.

On the second call, the else block is run and the for loop starts.  This is where my issue is.  As it is currently

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result)
```

starts all over again.  I was wondering if there is a way to choose where the fetching starts or if I would be better off fetching it once completely and then outputting the data?  Below is the code.

```
//This function will attempt to split the faq query into two containers
function faqQuery() {
$query  = "SELECT questionPosition, questionText, answerText
           FROM faqPage
           ORDER BY questionPosition";

$result = mysql_query($query)
or
die ("<b>Query Failed</b><br />$query<br />" . mysql_error());
```

/* $numRows is used to capture the number questions/answer pairs there are in the query.*/

```
$numRows    = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

/* $halfWay is used to find the median number of question/answer

```
pairs to near evenly split the number between two containers*/
$halfWay    = round($numRows/2);
```

/* This static counter is used to track number the of calls to the function.*/

```
static $counter = 0;  

//The first IF block generates the FAQ for div 1
if ($counter == 0) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$halfWay; $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $questionPosition   = $row[0];
        $questionText       = $row[1];
        $answerText     = $row[2];

    echo "<p class=\"faqText\">$questionText<br /><br />\n";
    echo "$answerText</p>\n";
    } //end For
//The ELSE block generates the FAQ for div 2
} else {
    for ($i=$halfWay; $i<$numRows; $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $questionPosition   = $row[0];
        $questionText       = $row[1];
        $answerText     = $row[2];

    echo "<p class=\"faqText\">$questionText<br /><br />\n";
    echo "$answerText</p>\n";
    } //End for
}//End else
$counter++; //Increment counter at the end of the function.
}//End function faqQuery();
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman Bobby is overrated, it's referring to multi queries which was not possible in `mysql_query()`, anyways still *+1*.

Comment: @Xorifelse You couldn't be more wrong. Look at [testing tools like this](http://sqlmap.org) and see how much they can can-opener your site with even the tiniest mistake. If there's a direct path to SQL injection it's game over for your site. It's just a matter of knowing what tricks to use.

Comment: @tadman Again, I'm referring to Bobby Tables that specifically is using multi queries. I'm not saying it cannot be injected. Hell, using PDO or mysqli isn't the cure for that either. Perhaps you should refer more to prepared statements instead of generally speaking about those libs.

Comment: @Xorifelse That quip is mostly a joke, but you'd be surprised what works. Prepared statements with placeholder values *does* fix this problem. PDO and `mysqli` support that, but PDO is more flexible and as a plus it's not MySQL-only.

Comment: @tadman I find it intriguing what people think of to steal your data, but yes I take PDO over mysqli any day. I took advice when PDO was new, never looked back.

Comment: @tadman currently, I only have access to the older versions of PHP/MySQL as someone is letting me use there server for a project.  They intend to get it updated soon but have been busy :p  I am very pre-cautious.

Comment: @WordWizard Is PHP 5.6 too much to ask? Been busy for about 3 and a half years?

Comment: `mysqli` has been around since at least PHP 5.0 which dates from 2004. There's really no reason to use `mysql_query` **at all** in a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch them all and interleave them as necessary, which is fine so long as you're assured that the records will *always* fit in memory. If you're not sure how many rows there might be, that it could be thousands or millions, you'll want to be more cautious.

An incremental approach uses the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clause on [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to better scope what you want. For example, to fetch the first 50 matches:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT 50
```

For the next 50:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
```

Keep in mind very high offset values can be a serious drag on performance, so test carefully, but that's the basics of pagination.